# How to disable scroll of the UIScrollview when it is in pannable?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm working on moving the `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView`. If the `UIScrollView` is not pannable then I could manage to trigger the `TouchesBegan` and `TouchesMoved` events but when the `UIScrollView` is zoomed and if I try to touch and move the `UIView`, scrollview is intercepting and started scrolling. I could not move the `UIVIew` freely across the `UIScrollView`.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

**Solution:**

I have found the solution by setting the UIPanGestureRecognizer `ShouldRecognizerSimultaneously` to true.

Comment: had a similar issue, I just implemented a double tap to put the UIImageView (In your case UIView) back to it's original size, which seems to be a fairly common mechanism in iOS apps, maybe that's an option for you?

Comment: I have posted the solution.